# Does a Venomthrope gets an extra attack for using multiple weapons?

Tags: warhammer-40k

This question is related to the 7th edition core rules and Codex Tyranids 6th edition:

The Codex has a "designer note" in the Melee Weapons section stating:

> Tyranid Melee weapons come as pairs. For game purposes, each pair is treated as a single Melee weapon. This means that **Tyranid models must fight with two pairs of any Tyranid Melee weapons to gain a bonus Attack in close combat for fighting with two weapons**.
>   [...]

(**emphasis** mine)

The Venomthrope model has 4 lash-whips, which seems to indicate it should get the bonus attack for multiple weapons.

But, the army list entry for Venomthrope simply states he has

> - Lash-whips
> - Toxic miasma

Unlike the Ravener entry, for example, which specifically states:

> - Two pairs of scything talons

So, does the Venomthrope gains the bonus attack? Given its base Attack attribute of 2, how many melee attacks can it make in a 'normal' assault phase (disregarding charge etc.)?

If possible, please support your answer with the relevant rules reference.
Thanks!

---

Updated note: as there are contradicting answers at the moment, I'm waiting to see some more up-votes or support from the rules before accepting any of them (both make sense IMO, but reach different conclusions)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the entry for Venomthropes does not list off "two pairs of scything talons" is because Venomthropes--unlike Raveners--have options for how to arm up that are zero cost.

Looking at the Fast Attack Ravener Brood entry, it lists under options:

> Any Ravener may exchange one pair of scything talons for rending
>   claws - 5 pts/model

In other words, a Ravener *will* have two pairs of scything talons--all the time--*unless* you pay 5 pts/model to switch it out, using this optional upgrade.

Let's focus on the Designer's Note you referenced:

> Designer’s Note: Tyranid Melee weapons come as pairs. For game
>   purposes, each pair is treated as a single Melee weapon. This means
>   that Tyranid models must fight with two pairs of any Tyranid Melee
>   weapons to gain a bonus Attack in close combat for fighting with two
>   weapons. For example, a Hormagaunt armed with a single pair of
>   scything talons does not gain a bonus Attack, but a Ravener with two
>   pairs of scything talons, or a Genestealer with a pair of rending
>   claws and a pair of scything talons, does.

If your model has four (4) lash whips, that is very straightforwardly two pairs of weapons.  Each pair is treated as a single melee weapon.  Your model therefore has two melee weapons and will gain a bonus attack in close combat for fighting with two weapons.

Or put another way:

1. set aside two lash whip models.  two bits, one pair, for game purposes single melee weapon.
2. set aside two lash whip models.  two bits, one pair, for game purposes single melee weapon.
3. does the venomthrope support holding all of the physical weapon bits?  If the venomthrope has all four weapon bits, the venomthrope has two melee weapons.

So in a normal assault-phase attack (non-charge), you would get **3 attacks**: 2 (base attack score) +1 (double melee weaps)

Comment: Can you please add how many melee attacks can it make in a 'normal' assault phase (disregarding charge etc.)? I'm guessing you mean it'll have 3 (base A2 + 1 for two sets of melee weapons) - right? I want to have the answers as easy to compare as possible.

Comment: (added at bottom)

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question. If the entry for them listed 2 pairs of lash whips, then you would indeed get an extra attack (per the Tyranid paired melee rule). Since it doesn't you don't get any. So 2 attacks, 3 on the charge, barring some other circumstance.

Comment: So, the model's 4 weapons are purely for esthetic value (or, rather, they are already reflected in its Attack 2 attribute)?

Comment: @G0BLiN The base attacks are in addition to the bonus attacks you get from multiple weapons. You'd get the 2 basic attacks + 1 for multiple weapons for 3 attacks. You would also gain any bonuses from charging as well.